# Order Dictionary by the result of other dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Looking for someone to help me with C#, LINQ.

I have a `Dictionary<int,int>` that I am ordering like so: `.OrderBy(_ => _.Value).ThenBy(_ => ThisMethodReturnsAnotherIReadOnlyDict<int,int>()).ThenByDescending(_ => _.Key)`.

What I want is to order the first dictionary by its value and then if there are still equal values I want that tie to be broke by the `ThisMethodReturnsAnotherIReadOnlyDict<int,int>()`. This first key/value of this `ThisMethodReturnsAnotherIReadOnlyDict` to break the tie and be on top. And finally, if everything fails, then order by it's key descending.

Some data for this like:

(First Dictionary)

```
[1,400]
[2,550]
[3,200]
[4,200]
```

(Second dictionary)

```
[3,50]
[4,140]
[2,600]
[1,700]
```

For this scenario I want my ordering to return: **[3,50]**

Can anyone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: What does "first key/value" mean in the context of a `Dictionary<>`? They have no order...

Comment: This is doomed to fail. "_For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined._" Source: [MSDN Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
var firstDict = new Dictionary<int, int>() {
    {1,400}, 
    {2,550},
    {3,200},
    {4,200}
};

var secondDict = new Dictionary<int, int>() {
    {3,50}, 
    {4,140},
    {2,600},
    {1,700}
};

var result = (from kvp in firstDict
             join tieBreaker in secondDict on kvp.Key equals tieBreaker.Key
             select new { kvp.Key, V1 = kvp.Value, V2 = tieBreaker.Value })
                .OrderBy(x => x.V1)
                .ThenBy(x => x.V2)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Key)
                .First();
```

This will join the first and second dictionaries together by its keys and will, respectively, order by the value of the first dictionary, the value of the second dictionary and then descending by the key itself.

Comment: Thanks Carlos! I think this works nicelly. But let's imagine that the second dictionary is empty. Then my join won't work. Any idea how to work around this and just use the first one? Thanks again!

Comment: @CharlieEcho, you might wanna perform some sort of left join. I'll edit the answer so you can use it better.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var ans = firstDict
    .OrderBy(kv => kv.Value)
    .ThenBy(kv => ThisMethodReturnsAnotherIReadOnlyDict<int,int>().TryGetValue(kv.Key, out var val2) ? val2 : kv.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Unless `ThisMethodReturnsAnotherIReadOnlyDict<int,int>` may change, you may want to cache the return value in a variable before sorting.